# Inline Quick Actions on a List View?

Tags: list-view, quickaction

I have created an object-specific Quick Action that executes a Lightning Component and I have added the action button to the object's Page Layout. The button is shown on the record page and it works perfectly fine.

But I would like the button to be shown on the object's list view as well. Salesforce standard functionality already includes several quick actions next to each record item in a list view:

[image]

Where are these "inline quick actions" specified in Setup? Is it possible to add custom ones?

I'm aware of the existence of "List Buttons" that can be added to a Search Layout, but those are not what I'm looking for because they are not record-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Actions in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.actions_in_lex.htm&type=5), that's not possible(except for the Task object)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add it from here,

Create new action on object by going to the Buttons, Links, and Actions menu.
Click the New Action button.

Then,

click `Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic` menu, then click Edit under the arrow on List View. New action you created should be available under "List View Actions in Lightning Experience"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but List View Actions or List Buttons don't apply to individual records or list view items, so it's not what I'm looking for. The screenshot I provided in my initial post shows exactly what I'm asking about: each list view item has a drop-down list with several actions (Edit, Delete, etc). Is it possible to add custom actions to that drop-down list?

Comment: You can't add specific to the record. I ll remove the answer since it doesnt help you